# Rails 4: Toggling a boolean value with link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to do a link to change a boolean value by ajax.

First of all, I tried [this tutorial](http://buckybits.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html), but it didn't work as well for rails 4.

I wish someone could shed light on the best practice of making it work.

I currently have the code below.

```
#ROUTE
scope 'admin', :module => "admin" do

    resources :users do
      collection do
        put 'toggle/', :action => :toggle_approve

      end
    end

  end

#CONTROLLER
def toggle_approve
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.toggle!(:approved)
  render :nothing => true
end

<!-- VIEW -->
<% @users.each do |u| %>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                  <td><%= u.name %> <%= u.last_name %></td>
                  <td><%= u.country %></td>
                  <td><%= u.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M") %></td>
                  <td>
                    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>'.html_safe, edit_user_path(u), class: 'btn btn-icon-toggle', "data-toggle "=> "tooltip", "data-placement" => "top", "data-original-title" => "Edit User" %>
                    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'.html_safe, url_for(:controller => "users", action: :destroy, id: u.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn btn-icon-toggle', "data-toggle "=> "tooltip", "data-placement" => "top", "data-original-title" =>"Delete" %>

                    <%= link_to "approve", toggle_users_path(u), :remote => true %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
```

The path **toggle_users_path(u)** is returning **users/toggle.2** instead of **users/toggle/2**

Someone have a better way to use the **remote: true** to make it work in the better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set up a route that accepts an `id` in the URL, so it's interpreting it as the `format` placeholder (hence the `.2` in the URL, which is usually reserved for a format like `json`, `pdf`, or `csv`).

Instead, the route should look like this, drawing on `member` instead of `collection`:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put 'toggle', :action => :toggle_approve
  end
end
```

That will hang the pattern off of the user's `id`, like this:

```
/users/:user_id/toggle
```

Then try this in your view:

```
<%= link_to "approve", toggle_user_path(u), :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

As you can see, you also need to post it along with a `put` method to hit your `put` endpoint.